# Checking if two results are the same not working

Tags: php, html, forms, url, pdo

So I'm trying to display a message for the user of the account. So I'd go to the user profile `/index.php?username=joe`. If I was `Joe` you'd have the ability of post, so I'd show a post box. The issue for some reason the box shows even if you're not `Joe`. Here's my code

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $_GET['username']);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$username = $row['username'];

if (count($username) < 1){
    echo "User not found";
}


echo $_SESSION['user'];
echo $username;
?>
//Issue has to be here somewhere 
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true || $username == $_SESSION['user']) : ?>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8888/post/p.php">
            <input type="text" name="post" placeholder="Post">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

<?php else: ?>
<!--Display sign up and in-->
<p>Sign in </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So `echo $_SESSION['user'];` displays Allen, while `echo $username;` displays Joe. So I'd assume that the form shouldn't show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong operator. `||` means logical `OR`.

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true || $username == $_SESSION['user']) : ?>
```

Instead you need a logical `AND`:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true && $username == $_SESSION['user']) : ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but what you do here

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true || $username == $_SESSION['user']) : ?>
```

Says if you are loggedin OR you are User. I think you may want to change that to:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true && $username == $_SESSION['user']) : ?>
```